# Tried to make a simple addition program, why is the main class not recognizing the method 'adder'?

Tags: java, class, methods

This is the main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int result = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter the first number");
    number1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the second number");
    number2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    result = adder(number1, number2);
    System.out.println(result);
    keyboard.close();
}
}
```

This is the method class

```
package Relearn;

    public class methodology {
        public static int adder(int number1, int number2) {
            int num1 = number1;
            int num2 = number2;
            int sum = num1 + num2;
            
            return sum;
            }
        }
```

I had 'adder' in the main class with private instead of public and it worked fine putting the two variables together, when I moved it to the other class it does nothing but give me an error for line 14 [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
The method Adder(int, int) is undefined for the type tester
at Relearn.tester.main(tester.java:14)]

Comment: You should call adder like `    result = Relearn.methodology.adder(number1, number2);`. If that doesn't work, you've got to fix your classpath ("methodology" is pre-compiled, correct?)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes that I can see.

1. You mentioned, previously you used the adder function inside the same class, but then you moved it to other class. **Did you imported the function ?**
   If not, you can do it in two way-

- a) import the class (not required if same package) ie. `import Relearn.methodology;`
  then call `methodology.adder(number1, number2);`
- b) import the static function ie. `import static Relearn.methodology.adder;` - in that case you don't need to change anything.

2. Please follow the naming conventions. package name should be in lowercase and Class name should be in CamelCase.